# Problems adding Identity to ASP.NET Core project using EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to add `Identity` to my project so I can add login functionality (I'm following an online course). I've followed the instructions as below but I'm getting the following error when trying to add-migration to update my database with the changes:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
>   services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime,
>   Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different
>   patterns supported at design time, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I've tried specifically finding `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime` in NuGet packages and add it but it's not made any difference - anyone has any ideas?

---

Instructions followed to get to this point:

- Go to Dependencies > Manage NuGet Packages
- Add the following packages:
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI`
- Change where `AppDbContext` inherits from in `Models.AppDbContext` - 
  Change 
  `public class AppDbContext : DbContext` 
  to
  `public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`
- Do a new migration and update database to make these changes to the database

EDIT:
My Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MLD.Models;

namespace MLD
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); // need to pass in the connection string here
            services.AddControllersWithViews(); // brings in support for working with MVC in .Net Core
            services.AddScoped<Repository>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSession(); // brings in session capability
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection(); // redirects HTTP to HTTPS
            app.UseStaticFiles(); // makes sure it serves JS, CSS, images
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=LymphSite}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your `StartUp.cs` to the question.

Comment: If adding the identity config in startup.cs still can't solve the first issue , you might need to  upgrade SDK to 3.1.101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for working with Identity you should add Identity to your `services`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

We also need to add the `middleware`. The location of where we insert the middleware is important. add below code **before** `app.UseEndpoints` middleware.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=LymphSite}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

you can find more explanation about how configuring `Identity` in this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_identity_configuration.htm).

let me know what happened. good luck.

Comment: Thanks for this - the UseAuthentication etc. was the next step in the tutorial but supposedly the migration should have worked without that? Either way I made these changes and ran the migration and it seems to work now. 

Something weird was going on with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime (trying to find v3.1.1.0 when the latest version was 2.2.0), but updating Visual Studio and/or your answer seems to have solved the issue